# Clustering in Python- Image Clustering

Tags: python, machine-learning, cluster-analysis

I want to cluster the images using K Means or other algorithm(suggestion required).

The problem is like this- I want to cluster images into 3 clusters (nature, sunset, water). I loaded all the images using os.listdir() and then converted all of the images into arrays (RGB) and then created a data frame which contains three columns - ID, Image_array, Label.

Now, when I use K Means clustering, providing n_clusters = 3, it shows this error:

> from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
>   kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters = 3).fit(img_array)
>   ERROR = Found array with dim 4. Estimator expected <= 2.

Now, I need your help in this clustering problem. The data frame that I created looks like this
[image]

```
img_array = []

path = "C://Users/shivam/Desktop/freelancer/p22/data/green_nature/"
for f in os.listdir('.'):
    if f.endswith('.jpg'):
        img = Image.open(f)
        data = np.asarray(img, dtype='uint8')
        img_array.append(data)


df = pd.DataFrame({'image_arrays':img_array})
df['id'] = range(1, len(df) + 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Well as you said, k-means would like a vector per input, whereas you provide it with a 3d array per image. The easiest way to solve a problem like this (which does require some creativity) would be to devise a set of features that are descriminating for the classes you have.

Since in this case you wish to classify between nature (lot's o' green), water (lot's o' blue) and sunset (lot's o' read/yellow/pink maybe?) you could use the total or average green blue and red values. To check if the features you have selected are discriminative, you can plot a histogram.

to go from your 4D (image x width x height x colour) array to a 2D (image x average colours) array. You need to take the np.mean over the colour, height, and width diminsions. In the end you should have an (images x 3 (colours)) array.

Comment: Yes, that seems interesting.But I am stuck, can you help me out in that. 

How to get the histogram (i actually also tried to get that).Now, I am trying to get the avg in place of 3 D array. If you please provide more help, that would be very helpful.

Comment: I am thinking to convert this 3 D array into a 2D array, that has mean and standard deviation, which will be ok when i run K Means, but this array is RGB array. I mean how to do that?

Comment: np.mean(image_arrays,axis=2)? https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.mean.html

Comment: I was also trying the same thing, bu t have some questions?
the array was 4D, used np.mean(axis =2), we cut off the fourth dim, now then I used axis = 0 again. we cut another dim. 

Now it is a 2D array, which will be accepted by K MEANS, but, i am confused, was that right to do so? 

How about if we use ndarray.flatten chop into a 1 D array and get the mean??

Comment: If you do the latter you get the average over the colours too, which will likely result in a lot of data being lost.

Comment: Hii, Its a 2D array now, but classes i am having is 300. after applying axis = 0,2 respectively.

But my dataset has only 24 instances, where i did mistake.

Comment: you should mean over axis 1 (width) and 2 (height), as those are the dimensions you want to get rid of....

Answer (score 0):

This happen because you pass 4-dim array while 2-dim expected. 'img_array.shape' should be like this (n_samples, n_features).
You need to use feature extraction algorithm.

This can be done via scikit-image module.
You need to convert images to greyscale format.
Code:

```
import skimage.feature as feature
img_converted = []
for i in range(len(img_array)):
    img_converted.append(feature.hog(img_array[i]))
model.fit(np.array(img_converted))
```

Documentation: http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.feature.html#hog

Comment: I need more explanation, can you provide me with your code.
At this point of time, I am thinking how to convert the array, to another 2 D array, which has mean and std dev for each row, which Kmeans can get

Comment: I was also trying the same thing, bu t have some questions?
the array was 4D, used np.mean(axis =2), we cut off the fourth dim, now then I used axis = 0 again. we cut another dim. 

Now it is a 2D array, which will be accepted by K MEANS, but, i am confused, was that right to do so? 

How about if we use ndarray.flatten chop into a 1 D array and get the mean??

Comment: I was unable to use that, what i did is , I converted the img_array to a 2D array by getting np.mean at axis=0 and axis= 2 respectively. 

now but classes i am having is 300. after applying axis = 0,2 respectively. But my dataset has only 24 instances, where i did mistake?

Comment: img_array.shape = (24, 300, 400, 3)